# Where is my disk space? Seems like a lot is missing

Tags: linux, installation, raid

I recently installed Rocky Linux 9.1.  I have four 4TB disks.  During the install I asked for custom partitioning and selected RAID 5 for /home and left everything else as default.

Here's what I wound up with in /proc/mdstat:

```
[root@server2 md]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md125 : active raid5 sdh4[3] sdg4[1] sdf6[0]
  6988820480 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
  bitmap: 0/27 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid4 sdh2[3] sdg2[1] sdi[4](S) sdf4[0]
  700628992 blocks super 1.2 level 4, 512k chunk, algorithm 0 [3/3] [UUU]
  bitmap: 0/3 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid5 sdh6[3] sdg6[1] sdf8[0]
  48896000 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
  bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

And here's what df tells me:

```
[root@server2 md]# df
Filesystem                      1K-blocks        Used  Available Use%     Mounted on
devtmpfs                             4096           0       4096   0% /dev
tmpfs                            16281172           0   16281172   0%        /dev/shm
tmpfs                             6512472       11416    6501056   1%     /run
/dev/mapper/rl_server200-root    73364480     7292160   66072320  10% /
/dev/sdf2                         1038336      472292     566044  46%     /boot
/dev/md126                      700286888    60635688  639651200   9% /home
tmpfs                             3256232          52    3256180   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                             3256232         100    3256132   1% /run/user/1000
```

You can see that the installer created a RAID 4 for /home instead of RAID 5, which is puzzling but I can live with it.

More importantly, it created md125 which has by far the largest amount of space allocated to it.  I can't see where this is mounted or used for anything.

Why is my /home so small?  How do I use the space assigned to md125?

If output from another command would help, please let me know.

---

The hidden space appears to be in /md125.  How do I get to use that?

Output of pvs:

```
  PV         VG           Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sdf3  rl_server200 lvm2 a--  28.57g  8.00m
  /dev/sdf7  rl_server2   lvm2 a--   5.24g     0
  /dev/sdg1  rl_server200 lvm2 a--  28.57g     0
  /dev/sdg5  rl_server2   lvm2 a--   5.24g     0
  /dev/sdh1  rl_server200 lvm2 a--  28.57g     0
  /dev/sdh5  rl_server2   lvm2 a--   5.24g 12.00m
```

Output of vgs:

```
  VG           #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  rl_server2     3   1   0 wz--n- <15.73g 12.00m
  rl_server200   3   2   0 wz--n-  85.72g  8.00m
```

Output of lvs:

```
  LV   VG           Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  swap rl_server2   -wi-a----- 15.71g
  root rl_server200 -wi-ao---- 70.00g
  swap rl_server200 -wi-ao---- 15.71g
```

Output of lsblk -M

```
                NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
                sda                     8:0    1     0B  0 disk  
                sdb                     8:16   1 114.6G  0 disk  
                └─sdb1                  8:17   1 114.6G  0 part   
                sdc                     8:32   1     0B  0 disk      
                sdd                     8:48   1     0B  0 disk  
                sde                     8:64   1     0B  0 disk  
                sdf                     8:80   0   3.6T  0 disk  
                ├─sdf1                  8:81   0     1M  0 part  
                ├─sdf2                  8:82   0     1G  0 part  /boot
            ┌┈▶ ├─sdf3                  8:83   0  28.6G  0 part  
            ┆   │ └─rl_server200-swap 253:2    0  15.7G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
         ┌┈▶┆   ├─sdf4                  8:84   0 334.2G  0 part  
         ┆  ┆   ├─sdf5                  8:85   0     1G  0 part  
      ┌┈▶┆  ┆   ├─sdf6                  8:86   0   3.3T  0 part  
   ┌┈▶┆  ┆  ┆   ├─sdf7                  8:87   0   5.2G  0 part   
┌┈▶┆  ┆  ┆  ┆   └─sdf8                  8:88   0  23.3G  0 part  
┆  ┆  ┆  ┆  ┆   sdg                     8:96   0   3.6T  0 disk  
┆  ┆  ┆  ┆  ├┈▶ ├─sdg1                  8:97   0  28.6G  0 part  
┆  ┆  ┆  ├┈▶┆   ├─sdg2                  8:98   0 334.2G  0 part  
┆  ┆  ├┈▶┆  ┆   ├─sdg4                  8:100  0   3.3T  0 part  
┆  ├┈▶┆  ┆  ┆   ├─sdg5                  8:101  0   5.2G  0 part  
├┈▶┆  ┆  ┆  ┆   └─sdg6                  8:102  0  23.3G  0 part  
┆  ┆  ┆  ┆  ┆   sdh                     8:112  0   3.6T  0 disk  
┆  ┆  ┆  ┆  └┬▶ ├─sdh1                  8:113  0  28.6G  0 part  
┆  ┆  ┆  ├┈▶ ┆  ├─sdh2                  8:114  0 334.2G  0 part  
┆  ┆  └┬▶┆   ┆  ├─sdh4                  8:116  0   3.3T  0 part  
┆  └┬▶ ┆ ┆   ┆  ├─sdh5                  8:117  0   5.2G  0 part  
└┬▶ ┆  ┆ ┆   ┆  └─sdh6                  8:118  0  23.3G  0 part  
 ┆  ┆  ┆ ┆   └┈┈rl_server200-root     253:0    0    70G  0 lvm   /
 ┆  ┆  └┈┆┈┈   ┈md125                   9:125  0   6.5T  0 raid5 
 ┆  └┈   ┆┈┈   ┈rl_server2-swap       253:1    0  15.7G  0 lvm   
 └┈      ┆┈┈   ┈md127                   9:127  0  46.6G  0 raid5 
         └┬▶    sdi                     8:128  0   3.6T  0 disk  
          └┈┈┈┈┈md126                   9:126  0 668.2G  0 raid4 /home
                sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Can you show a `lsblk -M`?

Comment: It looks lilke a lot of your space is in /dev/md127 - and that is not mounted.   Looking at your partitioning it looks quite munted - I would be inclined to back up anything important, zero the partition tables and start again.  I guess you could avoid this with a lot of juggling of data and adding /dev/md126 and /dev/md127 to LVM.  **I posit the missing space is in /dev/md127 and is hidding, unused, in the LVM**    You may want to provide the output of **pvs; vgs; lvs** to help us confirn this hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Requested info above.

Comment: Thanks to all who responded.  The missing space indeed is in md125.  I have no idea why the installation program created that.  Someday when I run out of space I'm going to have to reconfigure.  In the meantime, I figure I can mount the RAID and symlink to it. I would mark this closed if I could figure out how to do that.